# php Fatal error: Call to undefined function when is already defined in a different file

Tags: php

I have home page and a seperate file display_functions.php from where I am calling function
    file home.php

```
file display_functions.php 
html_header($title)
{
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xHTML1/DTD/xHTML1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"
xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 

<title><?php echo $title;?></title>
<link href="home_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>;
}


html_footer()
{

}
```

getting error:
html_header($title) { ; } html_footer() { }
( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function html_header()
need help

Comment: are you including the file that contains the definition for html_header in the current execution space.

Comment: Show your actual code. We are not declaring function like `function_name($variable){}`. The right syntax is `function function_name($variable) {}`

Answer (score 1):

your code is error..
You should wrapped the code which inside the html_header function whith echo,
and 
html_header() is a function, so you need add a function keyword before it.

Answer (score 0):

That error happens because you put HTML tags directly in your PHP source (it's a syntax error). I guess you meant using `echo` on them?

And, in general, saving yourself from boilerplate code in this manner isn't a good idea. Better create templates or use an MVC framework.